# Can one get banned without breaking the Code of Conduct?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension, code-of-conduct

Note: While this question is based on my experience, I intend this question to be general and useful.

I am not going into specific details, since I intend the question to be as general as possible. I was banned from using this Meta site for 30 days after leaving a comment. To the best of my knowledge, I did not go against the Code of Conduct. The message I got was short - basically the moderators banned me for bringing a certain topic up. Is this a form of censorship? Why can't we discuss freely and constructively on the Meta sites? Is that not what the Meta sites are for?

This is the message the moderation team sent me when suspending me:

---

> Hello,
>
> We're writing in reference to your Meta Stack Exchange account:
>
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/946172/shashank-v-m
>
> In a message to you from February 24th, a moderator clearly explained
> to you not to carry on an issue from MSO on this site.
>
> Since your latest edits to this post, the questions you asked tonight
> and the comments you made here clearly indicate you are still
> attempting to do so, consider yourself suspended on this site too now.
>
> We have temporarily suspended your account; you may return after 30
> days.
>
> Regards, Meta Stack Exchange Moderation Team

Comment: You were not suspended just for bringing a topic up. You were suspended for disobeying clear instructions from a moderator. In addition to the edit mentioned in the mod message, you also posted [this deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362906/why-are-we-getting-electronics-questions-on-stack-overflow) that also blatantly disobeys the instruction.

Comment: We can't comment on moderator action since we're not moderators. However, the smart money is on the fact that there was an infraction of some kind, and debating it in the court of public opinion is gonna do you more harm than good.

Comment: You were also suspended on SO when you received those instructions, so posting about them here isn't merely posting off-topic questions, but evading that suspension, which also contributed to your suspension here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not everything 'wrong' is in the code of conduct - the code of conduct is very much about the dealings we have with each *other*.  There can potentially be issues that might not be in the COC but may affect the running of the *site*

> In a message to you from February 24th, a moderator clearly explained to you not to carry on an issue from MSO on this site.

We asked you not to do it. We didn't suspend you at the time. We clearly let you know what the issue was.

> Since your latest edits to this post, the questions you asked tonight and the comments you made here clearly indicate you are still attempting to do so, consider yourself suspended on this site too now.

Which indicates, of course, that the behaviour continued. There's not much point in constantly redrawn lines in the sand.

While many of the specifics have evolved over time I'll refer you to the [original blog post about suspensions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)

> Our general strategy is to discourage specific problem behaviors, not individual users. But sometimes you just can’t seem to reach people, and it becomes necessary to place accounts in timed suspension.

So, as per your own account, we made an attempt to let you know what was the issue. The behaviour continued (and I'd suggest you review your own moderator message thread) and we attempted to discourage you further.

That said, the moderation team isn't infallible - If you feel that this decision was in error, you can and should escalate it to the community team. They'll be able to look at the full situation and review our handling of your actions.

Comment: Could you be more specific what this "behaviour continued" means? What "behaviour" and why is it discouraged?

Comment: 'Proper use of this site' is not bothering and wasting the time of people here by dragging an argument from Meta.SO to here, just because you can't get attention for it on MSO anymore. We are *most definitely* here to help out when people repeatedly exhibit improper use of the site, that's what a mod does. Your comments were deleted because they were blatant misinformation, claiming deleted answers where there are none.

Comment: @ShashankVM I don't know the details, but let's use a simple example instead. Suppose you have issue with a user called Bob, on Meta Stack Overflow. Bob and you have issues, and on MSO you informed mods and it's handled. You're not happy with how it's handled, so you start to ask here, on Meta Stack Exchange, for help with your Bob issue. Since it's only specific to MSO, you're asked to stop talking about it here. But you keep talking about Bob, despite being told not to, several times, by the mods here. You don't break the CoC, but you do break local site rules by not obeying the moderators.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I clearly remember that my answer to that question was deleted by your team.

Comment: @ShashankVM And I can see there are no deleted answers. Now, who would be right? Someone that can see evidence, or someone that claims to have a memory?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Okay I will write an answer to that question now. Let us see if it gets deleted.

Comment: @ShashankVM Make sure to stick to answering the question (and only the question) and to not just repeat existing answers, and it won't be deleted... it may end up downvoted though. Adding another answer there is probably a waste of your time anyways: The OP has probably long ago asked their question already.